# Doctrine 2 PlainValue expected

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-query

I'm having trouble executing a Doctrine DQL Query. This is the error it gives me.

```
Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException: [Syntax Error] Expected PlainValue, 
got 'integer' at position 13 in property Base\Session::$lifetime.
```

My code looks like this:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT s FROM Base\Session s WHERE s.session = \"$id\"");
```

Where $id is the current session_id. My Model looks like:

```
namespace Base;

/** @Entity @Table(name="session") */
class Session extends Skeleton {
/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer")
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/** @Column(length=32) */
protected $session;

/** @Column(type=integer) */
protected $lifetime;

/** @Column(type=integer) */
protected $modified;

/** @Column(type="text") */ 
protected $data;
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have two errors in this:

1. You have to double quote your annotations, i.e. `@Column(type="integer")` not `@Column(type=integer)`. Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException is thrown when your mapping is wrong. This has nothing to do with the query.
2. Your query should use prepared statements, i.e.

   `$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT s FROM Base\Session s WHERE s.session = ?1");
    $query->setParameter(1, $id);`

Comment: Thanks. The first error was the solution. I already knew your second point. Just tried so many things I ended up with this line of code in which I forgot to use the prepared statement. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As an additional comment to #1, single quotes do not work either, must be double quotes