# Troubleshooting "[Syntax Error] Expected PlainValue, got ')'"

Tags: annotations, doctrine-orm

I am getting this error in my annotations docblock for Doctrine 2:

`Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException: [Syntax Error] Expected PlainValue, got ')'`

After looking for an answer I found this reference [Stackoverflow Question 3500125](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500125/doctrine-2-plainvalue-expected) which in essence says to put quotes around all values in annotations.

With the annotation block I have this does not seem possible. here is my example that is throwing the error.

```
/**
 * @var tags
 *
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="namespace\to\tag")
 * @JoinTable(name="content_tag",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @JoinColumn(name="content_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * ) // This is the line indicated by the error
 */
private $tags;
```

If I follow the advice of the answer I found in stack overflow which is to quote out the values, my code will be like this:

```
/**
 * @var tags
 *
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="namespace\to\tag")
 * @JoinTable(name="content_tag",
 *   joinColumns="{
 *     @JoinColumn(name="content_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }",
 *   inverseJoinColumns="{
 *     @JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }" // Note the extra quotation marks
 * )
 */
private $tags;
```

Which is not right at all.

Comment: I have a many-to-many using the same syntax as you've got, the only differences being my indentation/placement and a cascade. Take a look: https://gist.github.com/1025638

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I am sure the syntax is right. but I still get the error. It is becoming very frustrating lol

Comment: The first code blocks looks valid and works for me. What version of Doctrine are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i found the error in my ways... and it is working now. See the answer below. To answer your question it was the 2.0.* stable release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a silly mistake, the error string was not very helpful as it pointed to the line i showed in my question as the line that the error was on. The fact was that this entity was extending a parent object, the parent had the @Entity tag but the child did not, i moved it and everything works fine.

Answer (score 75):

For people who have come here but not because of doctrine, my mistake was using single quotes instead of double quotes in the `@Routes` annotation.

WRONG:

```
/**
* @Route('/home')
*/
```

RIGHT

```
/**
* @Route("/home")
*/
```

Comment: This was my problem too. I solved it before I saw this post, but it is funny.

Comment: Old answer... still fixing issues. I was knocking my head against a wall on this one all day! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you man! This happens also in case when you use ' instead " in the name of the route.

Comment: Four years later - you'd think they'd allow single quotes by now. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I Just had the same kind of error by using an assert for an entity :

```
     * @Assert\Email(
     *     message = "The email '{{ value }}' is not a valid email.",
     *     mode = 'strict',
     *     normalizer = 'trim'
     * )
```

Turning it into

```
     * @Assert\Email(
     *     message = "The email '{{ value }}' is not a valid email.",
     *     mode = "strict",
     *     normalizer = "trim"
     * )
```

Fixed it :)